# How to change object value in a loop in Dart

Tags: dart, reference, variable-assignment

I'm a total newbie in Dart and I've a lot of issues trying to change a member value of an Object inside a loop.

I've my object so defined:

```
class Cell {
  int magicnum, x, y;

  Cell(this.magicnum);

  toString() {
    return ("$magicnum - [$x][$y]");
  }
}
```

I create a List of List of Cell (2d array) and then I need to fill x and y value according to position of each object in array.

```
for (int x = 0; x < DIM; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < DIM; y++) {      
      grids[x][y].x = x;
      grids[x][y].y = y;      
    }
  }
```

This obviosly doesn't work because in Dart everything (also integer) is an Object and so, all Cell objects in my array have the same x and y value (they all got a reference to the same object).
How can I do?

Thanks

@julemand101
Array is made this way:

```
List<Cell> cells = List<Cell>.generate(DIM, (i) => Cell(i + 1));
  List<List<Cell>> grids = List<List<Cell>>();

  for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
    grids.add(shuffleCell(cells));
  }
```

Comment: Did you try it? int is not a mutable object so when you say `x++` you are actually creating a new instance (in OOP sense) and does not modify the existing one (in theory... in practice int are represented like a normal int behind the scene).

Comment: So if you did try it and still see that all objects in your grid shares the same variables, could it be that when you create your 2d array that you forgot to create a new `Cell` object for each coordinate?

Comment: Can you provide a full running example (which can just be pasted into e.g. https://dartpad.dev) showing the problem? I have some difficulties trying to guess how each of you components are bound together.

Comment: Yes. [link](https://gist.github.com/fgrenoville/28d3f0117c549acdcddaf4ef9ac5a962)

Comment: Also, it seems to be you are only creating cells one time but are sharing them for each grid in `grids`?

Comment: You problem is you think you are cloning the `Cell` objects with `List<Cell> newlist = List<Cell>.from(items);`. Instead, you are creating a new List containing references to the same `Cell` objects as the previous list.

Comment: @julemand101 yes you're right... But in ```shuffleCell()``` I create a new list using ```.from()```

Comment: @julemand101 How can I correctly clone the list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211443/discussion-between-julemand101-and-ico).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is you are not actually cloning each `Cell` object when you are doing the following (taken from the code example from comments):

```
List<Cell> newlist = List<Cell>.from(items);
```

Instead, you are creating a new `List` containing the same references to `Cell` objects as the previous list of items.

To create a copy of `Cell` objects you need to implement a clone method like:

```
class Cell {
  int magicnum, x, y;

  Cell(this.magicnum);

  Cell.from(Cell cell)
      : magicnum = cell.magicnum,
        x = cell.x,
        y = cell.y;
}
```

And do the following to iterate each element of the old list, create a new `Cell` object for each element and convert the result to a new List:

```
List<Cell> newlist = items.map((item) => Cell.from(item)).toList();
```